# I can't see the value of my select in browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, json

I've made a select in which the options are taken from a JSON file by a JavaScript function.

The problem is that my list is visible but not the text, I got a blank space which when I click it, the value is registered, but you can't see which one it is. Here is part of the JSON code:

```
[{"id":"id_App","nom":"name_App"},
{"id":"id_App","nom":"name_App"}]
```

the html:

```
<label for="appli">APPLICATIONS</label>
        <select id="appli" name="appli" >
            <option value="default" hidden>--Veuillez selectionner une application--</option>
        </select>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
function populateApp() {
    fetch('./json.json')
    .then((response) → response.json())
    .then((json) → {
    const appli = document.getElementById('appli');

    json.forEach((app) → {
      const option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = app.id;
      option.textContent = app.name;
      appli.appendChild(option);
    });
 })
.catch((error) → {
console.error('Error fetching JSON:', error);
});
}
```

And the [screenshot of the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVvYD.png).

What can I do to make it visible?

I tried to change the colors of the select text, but it is already black, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: We can't help you debug code you've not shown us. I would suggest starting by using the DOM inspector to check what `color` is applied to that `select` elemnt

Comment: We can not "debug" screenshots. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: _"Here is the code:"_ - that's still not fulfilling the "reproducible" part. We don't know what that JSON you are fetching there actually contains.

Comment: `option.textContent = app.name;` - according to the JSON example you have given, the property holding the app name is named `nom`, and not `name`.

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been reopened, it appears to still be caused by the "name"/"nom" typo mentioned above. (As far as we can tell, since there's also still no reproducible example)

Comment: @DBS I know I don't understand why it has reopened either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the JSON example you have given, the property holding the app name is named nom, and not name.

–CBroe